# How to create timelimited personal link using DRF and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, next.js

I've got a frontend application implemented using React Framework. I need to give access to this application by timelimited (several hours) personal link. There's no additional authentication functions needed.  There are about 1-2 new users per day.
So implementation I came to is like this:

1. I implement backend API which is responsible for generating, storing and checking personal keys using Django Rest Framework
2. Keys are used as a part of URL to access react-application
3. Keys generation is done by build-in Django admin page
4. User is accessing page passing generated personal key in URL
5. React-application calls backend API passing key to check if user can access appication

I wonder is this solution is a good one? Is it possible to implement this functionality without backend (for example using nginx or any other devops tools)? Is there any package for django rest framework which already has implementation I need?

Comment: Hi, as far as I can tell, yes your implementation is a good one. The key generation and validation can also be done on the devop's level using tools like nginx but this your approach is more flexible and easy to manage.

Comment: ⚠️️ Software recommendation questions are **off-topic** here for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you have proposed for implementing a time-limited personal link for accessing your React application seems reasonable. The use of a backend API to generate, store, and check personal keys, as well as using Django Rest Framework to build the API, is a good choice as it allows you to easily manage the keys and check their validity.

It is possible to implement this functionality without a backend, for example, using a reverse proxy like Nginx. You could configure Nginx to handle the generation and checking of the personal keys, and to redirect the user to the React application if the key is valid. But in this case, you will need to handle the storage of the keys, and the complex configuration of Nginx.

As for the package for Django Rest Framework, there isn't any package that already has the implementation you need, but you can use some packages like Django-temporary-tokens which allows you to create, validate and expire tokens. Or you can use other libraries like django-cors-headers, djangorestframework-jwt, and djangorestframework-simplejwt for JWT token generation and validation.

In summary, the solution you proposed is a good one, but you should also consider the option of using Nginx or other devops tools. You should also consider using existing libraries or packages that can help you to handle the token generation and validation.